# Stack around the variable "name" was corrupted C++

Tags: c++, stack, c-strings

I'm trying to use CStrings to do miscellaneous tasks in C++, such as remove all the vowels from the name provided. However, I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error:

> Stack around the variable "name" was corrupted.

Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    void cStringDemo();
    void stringDemo();
    void removeCVowels(char myGuess[50]);

int main() {
    cStringDemo();
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
}


void cStringDemo() {
    char name[] = "Seth Smith";
    char guess[50];
    cout << "Guess my name! [First and Last, EX: Bobby Hall.]" << endl;
    cin.get(guess, 20);
    if (strcmp(name, guess) == 0) {
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    }
    else {
    cout << "Incorrect!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "You guessed " << guess << "." << endl;

    removeCVowels(guess);

}

void removeCVowels(char myGuess[50]) {
    char nameNoVowel[50];
    strcpy_s(myGuess, 100, nameNoVowel);
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        if (nameNoVowel[x] == 'a' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'e' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'i' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'o' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'u' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'A' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'E' ||
        nameNoVowel[x] == 'I' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'O' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'U')
    {
        nameNoVowel[x] = ' ';
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says everywhere the `guess` is 50, but you `strcpy` 100 - is that intended?

Comment: And... `cin.ignore();` at the end of `main()` is a bit superfluous.

Comment: Additional to what kabanus already said, in your `cin.get()` you write just 20 characters into your 50 character large array. Leading to you later (in your for-loop) addressing uninitilized data, posibly causing corruption (you probably do that in your `strcmp_s()` too)

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior:

```
void removeCVowels(char myGuess[50]) {
    char nameNoVowel[50];
    strcpy_s(myGuess, 100, nameNoVowel);
```

You are copying from uninitialized `nameNoVowel` to `myGuess`. You should swap the arguments of `strcpy_s`. Also, even if you swap the two arguments of `strcpy_s`, the limit of 100 is also too big, since nameNoVowel is only 50 chars. Try:

```
void removeCVowels(char myGuess[50]) {
    char nameNoVowel[50];
    strcpy_s(nameNoVowel, sizeof(nameNoVowel)-1, myGuess);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in the code that you posted. Below is code fixed with explanation in comments of what was wrong:

```
void cStringDemo() {
    char name[] = "Seth Smith";
    char guess[50] = {0};  //in here initialize the table with zeros
    cout << "Guess my name! [First and Last, EX: Bobby Hall.]" << endl;
    cin.get(guess, 20); // I am not sure why you want 20 characters and have array of size 50
    if (strcmp(name, guess) == 0) {
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    }
    else {
    cout << "Incorrect!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "You guessed " << guess << "." << endl;

    removeCVowels(guess);

}

void removeCVowels(char myGuess[50]) {
    char nameNoVowel[50] = {0}; //it is always good to initialize variables
    strcpy_s(myGuess, 50, nameNoVowel); //here lies the problem you tried to copy 100
                                        // characters from array size of 50 this leads 
                                        //to undefined behaviour of your program and stack corruption
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        if (nameNoVowel[x] == 'a' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'e' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'i' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'o' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'u' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'A' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'E' ||
        nameNoVowel[x] == 'I' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'O' || nameNoVowel[x] == 'U')
    {
        nameNoVowel[x] = ' ';
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that "*another problem*" is ***THE*** problem, your other remarks being (nice and founded) improvement suggestions. By the way,  for consistency purpose, you may have proposed the `= {0}` initialization for `nameNoVowel` where it could have been useful to prevent UB ;-)

Comment: @Christophe thanks for comments I edited the answer :)